# Unable to reimplementing the draw method of UIToolbar class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitoolbar

I'm unable to override the draw method of the UIToolbar class. I want to customize the toolbar with a background image and some buttons.

I tried this both in the AppDelegate.m and then also in my viewcontroller implementation file. here's my code:

```
@implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"tabbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

I'm adding the toolbar with this code in the view controller viewDidLoad method:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexiableItem, item2, nil];
    self.toolbarItems = items;
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe better add this code at application launch?

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```